# Making folder available offline - Access denied (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, files, offline-files

I have a drive on a server called "filestore"
This has a folder called "users"

in here, theres is a "users" folder. In there are folders such as - jsmith, jblogs, abrown - which correspond to usernames of our active directory.
When a user logs on, the H: drive is mapped to their above mentioned folder - for example //filestore/users/jsmith

I am trying to make one of these folders available offline in Windows XP.

when i do so, i get an access is denied error.
according to this - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275461 i need to make the root folder have read access to the users.

This means, however, all the users will be able to get in all the folders (if they browse to //filestore/users/)

How can I still achieve offline files for that particular users "h:" drive, and still have the other folders secured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the Users group read access to the root, but then take away inheritance on the individual folders and grant each user access to their own folder explicitly. This is basically how roaming profiles themselves work. Sounds like a lot of manual work but you could easily script it using the cacls command.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact issue. And I have already verified that the Users group has read access to the root but inheritance has been removed. This worked perfectly until I moved the file system to a new server. What am I missing?